# How do I define a function within a function in Clojure and reference that function?

Tags: clojure

I wrote a function to compute the symmetric difference of two sets (one of the problems on the [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com) site).  The function passed the unit tests, but it's not as clean as I would like, given that I have duplicated code.

```
(fn [x y] (set (concat 
  (keep-indexed #(if (nil? (get y %2)) %2) x)
  (keep-indexed #(if (nil? (get x %2)) %2) y))))
```

Obviously I would prefer something like:

```
(fn [x y] (set (concat (diff x y) (diff y x))))
```

Where the diff function is defined and referenced "inline", but I don't know how to do that in one fn block.

Comment: You can actually see other peoples answers on 4clojure (once you've completed the question) which should give you an idea of how you can tidy up your own attempts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a `let` or `letfn`:

```
(fn [x y]
  (let [diff (... function body here ...)]
   (set
    (concat (diff x y) (diff y x)))))
```

Answer (score 11):

One of the features that makes Clojure a lisp (and a functional language in general) is that **functions are first class things** in Clojure specifically they are Objects. When you make a function with `(defn name [arg] ...)` if builds the function and then stored it in a var so you can find it later from anywhere in your program. it's a lot like this:

```
(def name (fn [arg] ...))
```

now name contains a function that is widely accessible. Functions don't have to be stored in vars, especially if they are only needed within your function. In that case it makes more sense to bind the function to a local name as with Matt Fenwick answer.

```
(let [name (fn [agr] ...)] ...)
```

the `letfn` macro makes this more elegant.
The important part is to understand that functions are Objects that are stored in things, and you can choose the container that suits your needs.

Comment: Why did you say "The important part is to understand that functions are **Objects** that are stored in things"? Saying "Object" might lead someone to think you are talking about objects in the object-oriented sense. Lowercase "object", I think, might be better here. (I understand that Clojure is implemented on the JVM, where many things are implemented as OO Classes and Objects, but I don't think new Clojurians necessarily need to think about the implementation details.)